# Deleting a specific line in an MS Word document

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, ms-word, office-interop

I have been trying to delete a specific line from a word doc. The logic is , if I find a particular word in the document, I need to delete that particular line which contains the word. Do far I have only written the logic to find the word. However, tracing the line number ad deleting the line, I am unable to do. searched a lot I multiple websites, however, I am very puzzled now. Could you please help me out on this ?

below is my code:-

```
 void searchText(string txt)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = app.Documents.Open("C:\\Users\\SS5014874\\Desktop\\testdoc1.docx");
            object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
            doc.Content.Find.ClearFormatting();
            object keyword = txt.ToString();
            if (doc.Content.Find.Execute(ref keyword, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, 
                ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing))
            {
                //Need the logic to delete the line here
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Not found");
            }
            doc.Close(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
            app.Quit(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);            
        }
```

Please let me know if you need any other information.

NOTE: The search keyword is given by a textbox and the above function is called from a button.

Comment: check if this helps  http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/519686/deleteplusapluslineplusinpluswordplusfromplusVB-ne

Comment: @Dandy- Thanks for the response, however, this solution is for VB, not for C#

Comment: http://converter.telerik.com/ will do it for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like

```
var range = doc.Content;
if (range.Find.Execute(txt))
{
    range.Expand(WdUnits.wdLine); // or change to .wdSentence or .wdParagraph
    range.Delete();
}
```

Comment: It worked. the only change was instead of .wdLine, I used .wdParagraph. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate the paragraphs of the documents, then after you find the word in a specific paragraph you can delete the paragraph.

```
 newDocument = wordApplication.Documents.Open(fileDoc,
                                                     confirmConversions: false,
                                                     addToRecentFiles: false,
                                                     readOnly: true,
                                                     passwordDocument: Password)

 var docRange = newDocument .Content;

 foreach(var para in docRange.Paragraphs)
 {
   if(para.ToString().Contains("word"))
   {
     docRange.Delete(para);
   }
 }
```